# Jmeter-Beanshell -how to round up the price value

Tags: jmeter

How can i round up price value in bean shell?
For example:902.7 TO 903 OR 902.0 to 902

I have written below code,But it just takes off .00 from the code,i.e. if there is 92.00,It ll remove .00.But if there is 92.37,It wont change at all

```
String priceAdder(String Price,double per)
{
      prcv= Float.parseFloat(Price);
      prec=per*1/100;
      prec=prcv*prec;
      if(prec>95.00)
      {
          prec=95.00;
      }
      price=prcv+prec;
      price=price.toString();
      String[] ppr=price.split("\\.");
      if(ppr[1].length()==1)
      { 
          ppr[1]=ppr[1]+"0";
          price=ppr[0]+"."+ppr[1];
      }
      else
      {    //System.out.println("The value ppr[1]:"+ppr[1]);
         if(Character.getNumericValue(ppr[1].charAt(2))>=5)
         {
            Integer tadd=Integer.parseInt(ppr[1].substring(0,2))+1;
            if(tadd.toString().length()==1)
            {
                tad="0"+tadd.toString();
             }else{
                tad=tadd.toString();
             }
              price=ppr[0]+"."+tad.toString();
         }
         else
         {
            price=ppr[0]+"."+ppr[1].substring(0,2);
         }
      // price=ppr[0]+"."+ppr[1].substring(0,2);
}
 return price.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
originalPrice = Double.parseDouble(price);
roundedPrice = Math.round(originalPrice);
return String.valueOf(roundedPrice);
```

Should round your price to the nearest whole number. See [Math.round()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-) JavaDoc for more information.

Demo:

[image: JMeter Round Number Beanshell]

---

Be aware that starting from [JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31) [it is recommended to use JSR223 Elements and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting so consider migrating to [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) on next available opportunity.